# What does an object detection algorithm/neural network output?

Tags: python, neural-network

Currently I've got an (university) assignment where we need to create a neural network, using any technique, that can detect individual objects from images. But I feel I have  a lack of understanding how these algorithms work, I've now read papers about YOLO, CNN's and RCNN's. But one thing that is not explained (or at least not obvious to me), is what does such an algorithm (using bounding boxes to show where an object is) output.

I understand that the data that is input into these networks is an array of the pixel values of an image, but what is it's output?

How I believe it works is that the output of a 1-object detection algorithm would be an array that contains the height/width and the x/y position of the bounding box. But that leads me to this question: How can these algorithms generalize to *n* objects.

It kind of surprises me that this has never been explained to me at university, nor is it easily found. Every ***intro to object detection*** I find does not mention this *basic* fact.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple-object detection, one could "overlay" an image with a fixed grid. For each cell in the grid, the output would comprise whether or not a given object's centre of mass is contained within that cell, and subsequently what the bounding box dimensions are. This assumes that each grid cell contains the centroid of only a single object, which is often the case if your cell resolution is high enough.

The size of the network output is then proportional to the number of grid cells (e.g. each cell has XY coordinates of the object's centroid, width/height of the bounding box, and confidence factor that a unique object is present in the cell).